# How to use use Effect to determined what to display on the screen before another when a user clicked on a button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

```
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './Pages/Home';
import AboutPage from './Pages/About';
import ServicesPage from './Pages/Services';
import Meet from './Components/Meet';
import NavBar from './Components/layout/NavBar';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Meet text ='my meet up'/>
     <Meet text = 'my name'/>
     <Meet text = 'contact information'/>
      <NavBar/>
     <Routes>
      <Route path='/home' element = {<HomePage/>}/>
      <Route path='/about' element = {<AboutPage/>}/>
      <Route path='/service' element = {<ServicesPage/>}/>
     </Routes>
    
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And I <Meet text = 'my meet up' to be hidden when any of the Routes link is clicked

I tried using useState hook toggle to hide it but it couldn't worked out for me.
And what I'm expecting is when any of the ROUTES link is clicked, I want only its contents to be displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"And what I'm expecting is when any of the ROUTES link is clicked", which is to say, when the path is *not* any of the defined routes, show `<Meet text = 'my meet up'`.

```
<Routes>
    <Route path='/home' element = {<HomePage/>}/>
    <Route path='/about' element = {<AboutPage/>}/>
    <Route path='/service' element = {<ServicesPage/>}/>
    <Route path='*' element = {<>
        <Meet text ='my meet up'/>
        <Meet text = 'my name'/>
        <Meet text = 'contact information'/>
    </>} />
</Routes>
```

If you meant "show when on path /", change the asterisk "*" to "/".